Not able to access resource from another stack in AWS CDK
I am using AWS CDK with python, and my directory structure is as below.
├── README.md
├── app.py
├── bootstrap_scripts
│   └── install_httpd.sh
├── cdk.context.json
├── cdk.json
└── resource_stacks
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── custom_vpc.py
    └── web_server_stack.py

The files as as below.
resource_stacks/custom_vpc.py
from aws_cdk import (
    # Duration,
    Stack,
    CfnOutput,
    aws_ec2 as _ec2,
    # aws_sqs as sqs,
)
from constructs import Construct

class CustomVpcStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        prod_configs = self.node.try_get_context("envs")["prod"]
        self.custom_vpc = _ec2.Vpc(
            self,
            "customeVpcId",
            ip_addresses=_ec2.IpAddresses.cidr(prod_configs["vpc_configs"]["vpc_cidr"]),
            max_azs=2,
            nat_gateways=1,
            subnet_configuration=[
                _ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                    name="publicSubnet",
                    cidr_mask=prod_configs["vpc_configs"]["cidr_mask"],
                    subnet_type=_ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
                ),
                _ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                    name="privateSubnet",
                    cidr_mask=prod_configs["vpc_configs"]["cidr_mask"],
                    subnet_type=_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS,
                ),
                _ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                    name="dbSubnet",
                    cidr_mask=prod_configs["vpc_configs"]["cidr_mask"],
                    subnet_type=_ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
                ),
            ])
        CfnOutput(self,
                  "customVpcOutput",
                  value=custom_vpc.vpc_id,
                  export_name="customeVpcId")

app.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

import aws_cdk as cdk

#from mycdk.mycdk_stack import MycdkStack
#from mycdk.my_env_based_stack import MyEnvBasedStack
#from mycdk.context_var_stack import ContextVarStack

from resource_stacks.custom_vpc_including_tags import CustomVpcStack
from resource_stacks.web_server_stack import WebServerStack

env_USA = cdk.Environment(account="00000000000", region="us-east-1")

app = cdk.App()
#   MycdkStack(app, "MycdkStack",
#       # If you don't specify 'env', this stack will be environment-agnostic.
#       # Account/Region-dependent features and context lookups will not work,
#       # but a single synthesized template can be deployed anywhere.

#       # Uncomment the next line to specialize this stack for the AWS Account
#       # and Region that are implied by the current CLI configuration.

#       #env=cdk.Environment(account=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT'), region=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_REGION')),

#       # Uncomment the next line if you know exactly what Account and Region you
#       # want to deploy the stack to. */

#       #env=cdk.Environment(account='123456789012', region='us-east-1'),

#       # For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html
#       )
custom_vpc = CustomVpcStack(app, "MyCustomVpcStack")
WebServerStack(app, "MyWebServerStack", vpc=custom_vpc.custom_vpc, env=env_USA)
app.synth()

When I try to do ls, it gives error.
(venv) veer99@veers-MacBook-Air mycdk % cdk ls
[WARNING] aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.VpcProps#cidr is deprecated.
  Use ipAddresses instead
  This API will be removed in the next major release.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abcd/src/mycdk/app.py", line 58, in <module>
    WebServerStack(app, "MyWebServerStack", vpc=custom_vpc.custom_vpc, env=env_USA)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'CustomVpcStack' object has no attribute 'custom_vpc'

Subprocess exited with error 1

How can I access custom_vpc variable from the CustomVpcStack ?

What's the custom_vpc_including_tags file? It's not present in your posted folder structure

Based on your directory structure it looks like you need to replace
from resource_stacks.custom_vpc_including_tags import CustomVpcStack

with
from resource_stacks.custom_vpc import CustomVpcStack

Otherwise your code looks correct
